# C# Linq Query Bad Translates to the RQL in RavanDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an old project that was developed by the .Net framework and RavenDB 3 ...
I'm trying to migrate the RavenDB to the 5.* version
there is weird behavior in translate a Linq query to the RQL query

The below codes in c#

```
var query = documentSession
    .Query<Documents_ByOrgan.Result, Documents_ByOrgan>()
    .Where(x => x.OrganisationId == request.OrganisationId);

query = (from result in query

        let onboarding = RavenQuery.Load<IOnboarding>(result.OnboardingDocumentId)
        let onboradGroup = RavenQuery.Load<IGroup>(onboarding.Group.DocumentId)
        let invitedBy = RavenQuery.Load<User>(onboarding.InvitedByUser.DocumentId)                    
        let siteDoc = RavenQuery.Load<Site>(((Team)onboradGroup).Site.DocumentId)
        
        select new
        {
            OnboardingId = onboarding.Id,
            ...
        }).ProjectInto<T>();
```

Translates to the RQL in this way :

```
declare function output(result, onboarding) {
    var onboradGroup = load(id(onboarding.Group));
    var invitedBy = load(id(onboarding.InvitedByUser));
    var siteDoc = load(onboradGroup.Site.DocumentId);
    return { ... };
}
from index 'Onboardings/All' as result 
result.OnboardingDocumentId as onboarding 
select output(result, onboarding)
```

Why

```
let siteDoc = RavenQuery.Load<Site>(onboradGroup.Site.DocumentId)
```

translates to :

```
var siteDoc = load ( onboradGroup.Site.DocumentId );
```

BUT

```
RavenQuery.Load<IGroup>(onboarding.Group.DocumentId)
```

translates to the:

```
var onboradGroup = load ( id ( onboarding.Group ) );
```

**how can I prevent from generating id(..) in RQL?**

**id(..)** doesn't load any document

there is a lot of these queries in my project and all of them works fine with the 3.x version

In addition, I have the below config :

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = memberInfo => memberInfo.Name == "DocumentId";
```

there is a discussion [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-project-query-results#comment-5496342039) that helps me to find the problem

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/12475

It was released in 4.2.116/5.2.2.

Comment: Thanks @Grisha Kotler, What can I do? how to prevent generating id() in the RQL?
as you see, the `RavenQuery.Load<Site>(onboradGroup.Site.DocumentId)` generates a normal RQL, but `RavenQuery.Load<IGroup>(onboarding.Group.DocumentId)` tries to load the document by id(), 
which conditions cause this behavior?

Comment: What RavenDB client version are you using?

Comment: the last version, 5.2.1